# Доказательство с нулевым разглашением

Tags: математика, криптография

Классическим примером протокола доказательства с нулевым разглашением является протокол доказательства знания пароля к двери внутри круговой пещеры. Пусть Алиса (Alice) знает этот пароль и хочет доказать его знание Бобу (Bob) без разглашения самого пароля. Используется следующий протокол:
Алиса заходит в пещеру и подходит к двери с произвольной стороны так чтобы Боб не знал с какой стороны находится Алиса.
Боб заходит в пещеру и просит выйти Алису с какой либо из сторон пещеры (слева или справа).
Алиса зная пароль к двери всегда сможет выполнить пожелание Боба, появившись с любой стороны.
После каждой итерации уверенность Боба в том что Алиса знает секрет увеличивается вдвое. Таким образом после $k$ успешно выполненных операций вероятность того что Алиса на самом деле обманывает Боба равна $1/2^k$.

Вопрос: почему важно, чтобы Боб не знал с какой стороны входит Алиса? Ведь это знание не связано с секретом, а зная, например, что Алиса входит справа, Боб может попросить ее выйти слева и точно убедиться в том, что у нее есть ключ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В оригинале немного не так.

1. В начале квеста оба находятся в точке A. Далее Алиса проходит внутрь пещеры и поворачивает либо налево, либо направо, так что Боб не знает куда она повернула (выступ между A и B скрывает ее движение).
2. Далее Боб проходит к точке B и кричит Алисе выйди с левой или с правой стороны
3. Алиса по необходимости открывает дверь паролем и выходит либо слева либо справа.

Суть в том, что Боб не знает с какой стороны находится Алиса и наугад кричит выйди слева или справа.

То есть вероятность того, что Алиса применила пароль для открытия двери составляет как раз 50%. После N итераций уверенность Боба растет как `(1 - 1/2^N)`

[image: Пещера]
<sub>(источник: [mdr @ www.cs.bham.ac.uk](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emdr/teaching/modules03/security/students/SS2/handout_files/image002.jpg))</sub>

Comment: А если Боб будет знать, с какой стороны она зашла, то это не будет разве протокол с нулевым разглашением? Если не будет, то почему?

Comment: Тогда он сможет "управлять процессом". То есть, либо  заставлять ее всегда пройти через дверь, либо не проходить. Пропадает само понятие "выбора" и не нужно городить эту системы.

Comment: Смысл в том, что Боб может жульничать - то есть он зная, что Алиса заходит слева скажет ей слева же и выйти. А в случае, когда Боб не знает с какой стороны зашла Алиса нечестность проверяющего не влияет на конечный результат.

Comment: достаточно Алисе иметь сестру-близнеца, как вся эта проверка может пойти лесом:) (то есть, сестре достаточно зайти в пещеру раньше и заранее договориться с другой сестрой, куда она идет. Это все не противоречит условию - Бобу она ничего не говорит, а о том, что в пещере есть ещё кто то, там не упоминается).

Мораль. Используйте более надежные средства идентификации.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, и как именно нечестность проверяющего может повлиять на результат **этого** квеста?

Вот если бы они *вместе* демонстрировали знание пароля Алисой *третьему* лицу (здесь же оно не упоминается), то я согласен, знание Бобом куда Алиса повернула, помогло бы им совместно обманывать это третье лицо.

А если **именно Боб** хочет удостовериться в знании пароля Алисой, то от его знания направления движенния Алисы ничего не меняется. 

Кроме того (как уже сказал @KoVadim), что можно обойтись *одним* испытанием.

Comment: У нулевого разглашения есть 3 свойства:

   1. Если Алиса знает пароль она убедит Боба в том, что она знает пароль
   2. Если Алиса не знает пароля, то она даже жульничая не сможет убедить Боба в том, что знает пароль
   3. Если Алиса знает пароль, то даже нечестный Боб ничего не узнает кроме факта, что Алиса знает пароль

В варианте, когда Боб знает куда повернула Алиса - Боб может жульничать и таким образом может и не узнать знает пароль Алиса или нет. Касаемо сестры близнеца - то это одна из уязвимостей данного протокола. Идеала увы нет.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, другими словами, если Боб знает куда повернула Алиса и начинает жульничать (как это, не очень понимаю), то он обманет самого себя относительно знаний Алисы?

Comment: @avp, при доказательстве с нулевым разглашением стоит условие, что никакая информация не должна быть передана проверяющему. В случае с знанием, куда повернула Алиса, это условие будет нарушено и доказательство уже не будет "доказательством с нулевым разглашением". Все таки Боб-Алиса это только пример, который должен демонстрировать сам принцип.

Comment: @Alexey123, вот с 

    никакая информация не должна быть передана проверяющему

и надо было начинать (а может я прочел не все). Теперь понятно.